# Why is my function not returning the right value

Tags: java, enums

I have a function that sets the value if and only the value given is contained in with the enum declared. I'm then trying to get the value via get Method but I'm getting the default value. The setter method is not getting the new value and updating it.

```java
public enum BranchLocations {ONE,TWO,THREE,FOUR,FIVE};

private String BranchName ="Branch Name";

    public boolean setBranchLocation(String branchLocation) {
        for (BranchLocations b : BranchLocations.values()) {
            if (b.name().equals(branchLocation)) {
                this.BranchName = branchLocation;
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public String getBranchLocation() {
        return this.BranchName ;
    }
```

I'm learning enum currently and not very familiar with it. I'm just checking if the value is contained in the enum by a for loop and .equals method

### clarification  - tester im running it against

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args){

        Bank bank = new Bank("LhblVEWZXmtjn3gMykBaqfN& &h", Bank.BranchLocations.values()[0]);
        System.out.println(Bank.BranchLocations.values()[0]);
        System.out.println(Bank.BranchLocations.values()[1].toString());
        String newBranchLocation = Bank.BranchLocations.values()[1].toString();
        System.out.println(bank.getBranchLocation());
        bank.setBranchLocation(newBranchLocation);
        System.out.println(bank.getBranchLocation());
        System.out.println(
        (bank.setBranchLocation(newBranchLocation) && bank.getBranchLocation().equals(newBranchLocation)));

    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please show an example of a call to `setBranchLocation`?

Comment: What value of `branchLocation` do you use when calling the function? Have you tried printing the values of `b.name()` and see if they actually match your expectations?

Comment: Definitly need to include calling code. Its working just fine for me

Comment: You're using `toString()` in your test code and `name()` in your setter. It probably won't matter, but at least be consistent, as it may matter in other circumstances. Or maybe you didn't show us the actual `enum`, in which case it may matter right now.

Comment: You provided example of how you use that method but we can't run it because we don't have code which would let us invoke `new Bank("LhblVEWZXmtjn3gMykBaqfN& &h", Bank.BranchLocations.values()[0]);`. If we wrap your first example in `public class Bank{...}` and use `new Bank();` instead your code seems to be working fine. Can you include results you are getting from it and point out what is wrong with it?

Comment: @Pshemo Yes, wrapping it around public class Bank{...} will work, I cannot see why it wouldn't work for me but I tried .toString instead of .name and it worked

Comment: You should follow the Java Naming Conventions: method and variable names are always written in camelCase. That means that `BranchName` should be `branchName`. Also, a class name should be a singular noun. `BranchLocations`, for instance, should be just `BranchLocation`.

Comment: @ImYoonah123 "*I cannot see why it wouldn't work for me but I tried .toString instead of .name and it worked*" but both `toString()` and `name()` have same implementation which is `{return name;}` (`name` is hidden field holding name of value like in case `enum MyEnum{FOO}` value `FOO` would hold `"FOO"` string in its `name` field). That means changing `name()` to `toString()` shouldn't cause any difference. BUT if it really helped (try changing it back to `name()` to test if only that change helped you) then maybe you overrode `name()` method but didn't include that in your example.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In the enum, you have just declared the names, not the values. But, in your method, you are retrieving the values for the test. This is not the intended behaviour.

Do:

```
if (b.toString().equals(branchLocation)) {
   this.BranchName = branchLocation;
   return true;
}
```

or define a value for each one of the names in the Enum:

```
public enum BranchLocations {
    ONE("ONE"),
    TWO("TWO"),
    THREE("THREE"),
    FOUR("FOUR"),
    FIVE("FIVE")
};
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "In the enum, you have just declare the names, not the values"?

Comment: What is the difference between .toString // .Name ? Doesn't it just return the same value?

Comment: @Pshemo I edited the answer. In the case of my example, name and value match.

Comment: `values()` is a method generated by Java for each enum. It returns all enum entries in an array. So there is no need to write that method themselves.

Comment: `toString()` in enum simply returns value of hidden `name` field which holds same string as used in enum value, for instance `enum MyEnum{FOO, BAR}` will hold two enum values `FOO` and `BAR` and each of those values will have their own `name` field which will hold `"FOO"` and `"BAR"` respectively. Both `toString()` and `name()` are implemented as `{return name;}` so there shouldn't be any difference in using them.

Answer (score 0):

```
public enum BranchLocations {

    ONE("ONE"),
    TWO("TWO"),
    THREE("THREE"),
    FOUR("FOUR"),
    FIVE("FIVE");

    private String BranchName = new String();

    BranchLocations(String val){BranchName = val;}

    public String getBranchLocation() {return BranchName;}

    public boolean setBranchLocation(String branchLocation) {
        for (BranchLocations b : BranchLocations.values()) {
            if (b.name().equals(branchLocation)) {
                this.BranchName = branchLocation;
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: Thanks, @FedericoklezCulloca for your suggestion, I will try to add explanations as well. Here I thought the code is so simple and might not an explanation is needed, that's why I haven't added any explanation.